# wpa_gui error: 'Could not get status from wpa_supplicant'

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to follow Adafruit.com's [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/overview) on setting up WiFi on a Raspbery Pi. I have the B+ model.

I used Win32 Disk Imager to burn [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) to a microSD card.

I booted up my Pi and ran an update from the `rasp-config` menu.

Here's what I have plugged into my Pi:

- Wireless keyboard and mouse USB dongle
- Linksys AE2500 USB wifi dongle
- Ethernet cable that's plugged into my cable modem
- HDMI cable
- microUSB power cable

I boot up the Pi, log in, run `startx` to get to desktop, open a Linux terminal, and enter `sudo wpa_gui` to run wpa_gui.

But wpa_gui has nothing to select in the 'Adapter' and 'Network' dropdowns. The 'Current Status' tab's 'Status' section says 'Could not get status from wpa_supplicant.' There's nothing in the list under the 'Manage Networks' tab, and the 'WPS' tab is unclickable since it's greyed out.

Here's what `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

Here's what `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I also notice this error during bootup: `wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start`

I'm really not sure what to do. Internet works fine when plugged into the cable modem thru the Ethernet cable. But I want wifi to work.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

I hope you were able to find an answer to your question. 
But just in case you didn't or someone else has the same problem, here's what worked for me:

#### Your interfaces file should look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

#### Your wpa_supplicant.conf file should look like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
   ssid="your network/wifi name"
   psk ="your network/wifi pass"
   proto=RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   pairwise=TKIP
   auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

All the info after "psk" depends on your network settings. 
I think you should be able to run wpa_guide (wifi setup) even if you don't type out the network={....} in the wpa_supplicant.conf file.